# MsgBox function default fourth button

Tags: vba, button, default, msgbox

I noticed in VBA that the MsgBox function has a allowable constant of

> **vbDefaultButton4**

which will make the fourth button the default.
BUT of all the allowable constants for buttons, none give you four buttons.

Is there a way to get a fourth button on a MsgBox, or is this useless, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall, you can use `vbMsgBoxHelpButton` to add a Help button to your message box. That, combined with a 3-button dialog, would yield 4 buttons. You then use `vbDefaultButton4` to make Help the default button.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `vbMsgBoxHelpButton` in combination with an option that gives three buttons, there are four buttons.